# why will these tags not go on the same line?

Tags: html, css

here is the html, that for one reason or another, the li's and input's will not go on the same line

```
<div class="nav">
        <form class="searchbox">
        <input name="search" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="Galleries.html">Galleries</a></li>
     <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     <li><a href="Story.html">Story</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

this is the css to go with

```
.searchbox {
    display:inline;
    padding-right:2em; 
    padding-left:55em;
}

.nav {
    position:absolute;
    padding:.5em 0em .5em 2em;
    font-size:1.25em;
    margin:-3.5em 0em 98em 0em;
    background-color:black;
}

.nav li {
        display:inline-block;
        float:left;
        color:#7C6C5A;
}
```

this is going on a semi professional site, on four pages, so i need something that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "one reason or another" is that your `<ul>` is a block-level element.  Apparently you were going in the right direction, since you put `display: inline;` on the `<form>` and `display: inline-block;` on the `<li>` elements.

Since the `<ul>` is the sibling of the `<form>`, these should both have `display: inline-block;`.  And I might recommend some `vertical-align: middle;` action.

So I changed your CSS to:

```
.searchbox {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 2em; 
}

ul {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav {
    position:absolute;
    padding:.5em 0em .5em 2em;
    font-size:1.25em;
    margin: 0 0 98em 0em;
    background-color:black;
}

.nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    color:#7C6C5A;
}
```

And here is a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/e5sskx96/).  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```css
.content-box {
 margin: 0 auto 0;
 width: 1000px;
}
.nav {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 700px;
}

.nav li {

 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 6px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.nav li a {
 color: #444;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.searchbox {
 width: 250px;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-box">
 <div class="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="Galleries.html">Galleries</a></li>
   <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="Story.html">Story</a></li>

  <form class="searchbox">
   <input name="search" type="text">
   <input type="submit">
  </form>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how did you add that run code snippet part at the bottom